Conditionally ignoring tests with JUnit5
I'm writing tests for a custom library, that deals with databases. There are two requirements:

The testing should only be attempted, if the environment variable TESTDB is set.
Though the library uses JDBC, we only use it with MS SQL backend currently, and most of the tests are only valid for that.

I want the test-suit to behave gracefully, if the $TESTDB is not resolving, or if the specified backend is anything other than SQLServerDriver.
The first condition is handled with:
@DisableIfTestFails
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class SFTDbaasUtilsTest {

    public static final String DBNAME = System.getenv("TESTDB");

    @BeforeAll
    public static void checkEnvironment() {
        assumeTrue(DBNAME != null, "TESTDB not found in enironment");
        logger.info("DBNAME is {}", DBNAME);
    }
...

This works fine, and, when the environment variable is not set, mvn test reports: Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, just what I want.
However, for the second requirement, the best I can come up with is the custom checker to use inside the EnabledIf-decorator:
    private static BasicDataSource BDS = null;

    private static boolean isMSSQL() {
        return BDS != null &&
            BDS.getDriverClassName().endsWith("SQLServerDriver");
    }

...
    @Test
    @Order(30)
    @EnabledIf("isMSSQL")
    public void getConnection() {
        try {
            CONN = DS.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            fail("Connection to " + DBNAME + " failed", e);
        }
    }

This works causing the tests, which are so decorated, to be skipped. However, in the summary they are still counted as attempted (and skipped) instead of being completely ignored. The summary also includes a warning: [WARNING] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 7.
I'd rather the tally simply included the one attempted test (which is backend-agnostic) -- and that there were no scary "WARNING".
How would I do that?

Any test that exists is run, even if they are skipped. If you want to get rid of skipped tests, you can consider creating tests using @TestFactory and DynamicNode / DynamicContainer / DynamicNode.

@RobSpoor, I would've accepted this explanation, had the @BeforeAll failure not caused the count to be all zeroes...

@Slaw, yes, filtering (of some kind) is what I'm after. But can it be dynamic? That is, dependent on what JDBC back-end the specified DataStore is using?

@Slaw, no the "wrong" driver is only wrong due to limits of the existing test-coverage.  And, even if we had more tests for the other drivers, I'd still want to skip (not fail) the driver-specific tests meant for other drivers. This seems possible with JUnit tags, except I want the tags automatically discerned based on the JDBC-driver...

Caveat:  I'm using a spring boot project to test this, but the following has been tested and works for me:
In your application.properties file:
This will disable the test
yourProperty=true

This will enable the test
yourProperty=false

In your test file, load the application context if you aren't already, then add this:
@Value("${yourProperty}")
private boolean disabledVar;

The above pulls the property from your app prop file.
Your test:
@DisabledIf("deciderMethod")
@Test
void yourTest() {
    assertEquals(1, 1);
}

Then below, add this method:
private boolean deciderMethod() {
    return disabledVar;
}

That should be all you need to accomplish your end goal.
Granted, I'm using the app prop file, rather than an environment variable.  That said, Unit does have @DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable which may serve your purposes better.  I haven't had a need for this yet, so I'm unsure if it would work for you, but if you'd like more info, check out:  https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.2.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable.html
Hope this helps.

This will still count the skipped tests as such, wouldn't it? And produce the WARNING...
